# Javascript XML parser doesn't work

Tags: javascript, xml, parsing, dom

I know there are many questions and articles discussing this issue on the internet, but I somehow can't get this to work. I'm quite sure I'm missing something basic, but I can't find it.

The parsing itself:

```
var str="<article>Some article</article><other>Other stuff</other>";
var xmlDoc = null;
if (window.DOMParser) {
            var parser = new DOMParser();
            xmlDoc = parser.parseFromString(str,"text/xml");
        } 
else if (window.ActiveXObject) {
            xmlDoc = new ActiveXObject ("Microsoft.XMLDOM");
            xmlDoc.async = false;
            xmlDoc.loadXML(str);
        }


var node = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("article")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
alert (node);
```

But it doesn't work, FF says that:

```
xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("article")[0] is undefined
```

Also, it works if I use str like this:

```
var str="<article>Some article</article>";
```

So the question is, why doesn't it work? Parsing doesn't work right even if I append just one character to the end of str variable. Could you also point me  out to some useful tutorial regarding this behaviour?

Comment: Maybe because it's not a valid XML structure...?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your string isn't valid XML since it has multiple root nodes. Did you mean something like:

```
<article><name>Some article</name><other>Something else</other></article>
```

Answer (score 1):

try using

```
var str="<root><article>Some article</article><other>Other stuff</other></root>";


var node = xmlDoc.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("article")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;

documentElement property returns the root tag of an xml document , once you get the root tag, next you can extract elements by tag name , child nodes ....
```